# ¿Cómo consultar numero de registros de una fecha por horas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día amigos,

Supongamos que tengo la siguente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que me cuente por horas el número de registros, es decir, de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

intenté con:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tabla
 WHERE fecha between '2018-10-26 06:00:00' and '2018-10-26 17:00:00' GROUP BY TIME(fecha);
```

pero no me trae los registros de uno en uno.

Comment: serías tan amable de agregar lo que has investigado, tratado?

Comment: dale editar a tu pregunta y añade el código necesario ahi

Comment: Listo, creo que me falta cuadrar algo del sql pero no sé qué

Comment: listo espero el ejemplo que hice te sirva, muestra como lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tu query debería quedar de este modo:**

```
SELECT count(id) as total, DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%H:%i:%s') AS "#Registro"
from registros
group by fecha;
```

**LO QUE HICE**

1. Hago un conteo de los id
2. Le doy formato al campo de fecha para que solo tome la hora completa y omita la fecha
3. agrupo por fecha

**Muestra del código funcionando**

[Link al ejemplo funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f93877348082b48de61c15e238ab2ca)

Answer (score 1):

Te falto la columna fecha en la seleccion de los campos:

`select 
    time(fecha) as hora, 
    count(*)
from
    horarios
group by 
    time(fecha)`